# How to have perfect alignment of the following equation?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, theorems

I want to write the following text and mathematical expressions under Theorem environment. I want both of them to be left aligned.

Can you please guide me how to do that?

```
\begin{theorem}

The marginal distribution of `$\hat{\theta}_2$, for $-\infty<y<\infty$` is

    \begin{eqnarray*}
    \begin{split}
    f_{\hat{\theta}_2}(y)&=k\binom{n}{k} \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{\binom{k-1}{i}(-1)^i}{(n-k+1+i)}e^{-\frac{T}{\theta_1}(n-k+1+i)}f_g(y;n-k,\frac{n-k}{\theta_2})\\
    &+\sum_{i=k}^{m-1}\sum_{s=0}^i\binom{n}{i}\binom{i}{s}(-1)^s e^{-\frac{T}{\theta_1} (n-i+s)} f_g(y;n-i,\frac{n-i}{\theta_2})+m\binom{n}{m}\times\\
    &\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \frac{\binom{m-1}{i}(-1)^i}{n-m+1+i} [1-e^{-\frac{T}{\theta_1}(n-m+1+i)}]f_g(y;n-m,\frac{(n-m)}{\theta_2}
    \end{split}
    \end{eqnarray*}
\end{theorem}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  you can highlight your code by putting it between backticks if it's within text, or mouse-over a block and then click on the `{}` icon above the window.  also, it's most helpful if you can provide a small complete example, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}, so we can cut-and-paste to experiment.  finally, `\eqnarray` isn't the best choice of coding; here's some commentary on the subject: [`eqnarray` vs `align`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196).

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the `flalign*` environment. But I sugest ailso the `multline*` environment. The following code shows the possibilities, with some modifications of line breaking points. I also changed the size of some pairs of parentheses:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%
\usepackage{mathtools,nccmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
  The marginal distribution of $\hat{\theta }_2$, for $-\infty<y<\infty$ is
  \begin{flalign*}
    f_{\hat{\theta }_2}(y)=k\binom{n}{k} & \smash[t]{\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{\binom{k-1}{i}(-1)^i}{(n-k+1+i)}e^{-\frac{T}{\theta_1}(n-k+1+i)}f_g\biggl(y;n-k,\frac{n-k}{\theta_2}\biggr)} & & & \\
    {}+{}&\sum_{i=k}^{\mathclap{m-1}}\sum_{s=0}^i\binom{n}{i}\binom{i}{s}(-1)^s e^{-\frac{T}{\theta_1} (n-i+s)} f_g\biggl(y;n-i,\frac{n-i}{\theta_2}\biggr)\\
    {}+{}&m\binom{n}{m}\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \frac{\binom{m-1}{i}(-1)^i}{n-m+1+i} \Bigl[1-e^{-\frac{T}{\theta_1}(n-m+1+i)}\Bigr]f_g\biggl(y;n-m,\frac{n-m}{\theta_2}\biggr)
  \end{flalign*}
\end{theorem}
\bigskip

\begin{theorem}
  The marginal distribution of $\hat{\theta }_2$, for $-\infty<y<\infty$ is
  \begin{multline*}
    f_{\hat{\theta }_2}(y)=\smash[t]{k\binom{n}{k} \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{\binom{k-1}{i}(-1)^i}{(n-k+1+i)}e^{-\frac{T}{\theta_1}(n-k+1+i)}f_g\biggl(y;n-k,\frac{n-k}{\theta_2}\biggr)} \\
    {}+\sum_{i=k}^{\mathclap{m-1}}\sum_{s=0}^i\binom{n}{i}\binom{i}{s}(-1)^s e^{-\frac{T}{\theta_1} (n-i+s)} f_g\biggl(y;n-i,\frac{n-i}{\theta_2}\biggr)\\
    {}+m\binom{n}{m}\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \frac{\binom{m-1}{i}(-1)^i}{n-m+1+i} \Bigl[1-e^{-\frac{T}{\theta_1}(n-m+1+i)}\Bigr]f_g\biggl(y;n-m,\frac{n-m}{\theta_2}\biggr)
  \end{multline*}
\end{theorem}
\bigskip

\begin{theorem}
  The marginal distribution of $\hat{\theta }_2$, for $-\infty<y<\infty$ is
\begin{fleqn}
  \begin{align*}
     & f_{\hat{\theta }_2}(y)=\smash[t]{k\binom{n}{k} \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{\binom{k-1}{i}(-1)^i}{(n-k+1+i)}e^{-\frac{T}{\theta_1}(n-k+1+i)}f_g\biggl(y;n-k,\frac{n-k}{\theta_2}\biggr)} \\
 & \negthickspace+\sum_{i=k}^{\mathclap{m-1}}\sum_{s=0}^i\binom{n}{i}\binom{i}{s}(-1)^s e^{-\frac{T}{\theta_1} (n-i+s)} f_g\biggl(y;n-i,\frac{n-i}{\theta_2}\biggr)\\
& \negthickspace+m\binom{n}{m}\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \frac{\binom{m-1}{i}(-1)^i}{n-m+1+i} \Bigl[1-e^{-\frac{T}{\theta_1}(n-m+1+i)}\Bigr]f_g\biggl(y;n-m,\frac{n-m}{\theta_2}\biggr) \end{align*}
\end{fleqn}%
\end{theorem}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Bernard . But I want each new line of the expression starts right from the bottom of $f_\hat{\theta}_2(y)$. Can you please show some path in that direction ? Thanks in advance .

Comment: @pinku: I've added a third solution.

Comment: But the second one is best! ;-)